# Does this exist: HDD/SSD with Thunderbolt 3 AND Ethernet?

Tags: hard-disk, nas, ethernet, thunderbolt

I am looking for a hard disk/SSD/NAS with both these interfaces:

- Thunderbolt 3
- Ethernet, 1 GbE or 10 GbE

So far I only found TB+USB and Eth+USB.

Does the combination I am looking for exist?

Comment: What for? You're asking for a device that's both not a NAS and is one, which is a bit odd.

Comment: Since there are hard disks with both Ethernet and USB, I suppose there should be some with Ethernet and Thunderbolt. It will work as a NAS when Ethernet is used.

Comment: There are, but it's unusual. What's the use case?

Comment: The use case is mainly simulation.

Comment: Simulating what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, at last: [QNAP TS-453BT3](https://www.qnap.com/en-uk/product/ts-453bt3)